# Stored proc with 11+ dynamic parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows-server-2008, dynamic-sql

I know this question has been asked and debated before. The answers I have read are mostly opinion, so I am looking for something more technical. More "under the hood".

I'm using SQL Server 2008. I am about to write a query that will need to accept at least 11 inputs. The user could specify 1 to 11(+) of these. They are of various types (IDs, text matching, geography, full text matches, record sets, etc.). It's as dynamic as you can get with SQL.

I know how to do this without using dynamic SQL:

```
/*for simple match*/ WHERE @Input IS NOT NULL OR t.col = @Input
```

This has drawbacks because of joins etc. I don't ever use dynamic SQL. But from what I've read, it seems this may be a case for dynamic SQL.

Can anyone give some technical pointers please?

Comment: See [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) for quite an exhaustive examination of this topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.sommarskog.se/index.html

Look at the curse and blessing of Dynamic SQl and the Dynamic Search Conditions links

Answer (score 1):

You need to remember that if you don't want to use dynamic SQL (and I wouldn't either) then the DRY principle is sorta out-the-window.

Make effective use of TVP's and accept the fact that you will have somewhat high cyclomatic complexity (for a SQL statement)

If you want everything cacheable and sargable, you should consider how to design it in multiple procedures and then break out your conditions as needed.

Another very common approach is to include conditions such as:

```
WHERE (@pParam IS NULL OR ~condition~)
```

If your parameter is NULL then SQL will not bother resolving the other half of the condition.
EDIT: This last part only applies in SQL2008R2 and only if using the `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` command

Comment: Your last line is completely incorrect. This practice makes potentially seekable search predicates unsargable and leads to unnecessary table scans.

Comment: @Martin, I left out the important part about using `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` but the practice comes directly from Erland Sommarskog in the links posted.

Comment: That is a pretty important part to leave out! BTW it's actually SQL Server 2008 SP1 CU5 and up not just R2 this applies to.